# Python 3.8: Merging 2 compound lists

Tags: python-3.x, arraylist, concatenation

I have 2 lists:

```
l1 = [[1.56, 2.04],[0.69, 6.34],[1.14, 7.59],[1.35, 3.01],[0.92, 8.33]]

l2 = [[3.45, -11.53],[3.20, -11.60],[3.33, -11.56],[3.39, -11.55],[3.26, -11.5]]
```

I want to merge these 2 such that the output is:

```
[[1.56,2.04,3.45,-11.53],[1.14,7.59,3.20,-11.60],[1.14, 7.59,3.33, -11.56],[1.35, 3.01,3.39, -11.55],[0.92, 8.33,3.26, -11.5]]
```

The first element from the second list has to be merged with the first element of the first list, and so on.

I have tried:

```
l1 = [[1.56, 2.04],[0.69, 6.34],[1.14, 7.59],[1.35, 3.01],[0.92, 8.33]]
l2 = [[3.45, -11.53],[3.20, -11.60],[3.33, -11.56],[3.39, -11.55],[3.26, -11.5]]

l3=[]

for i in l1:
    for j in l2:
        r = i+j
        l3.append(r)
display(l3)
```

But the output is really strange:

```
[[1.56, 2.04, 3.45, -11.53],
 [1.56, 2.04, 3.2, -11.6],
 [1.56, 2.04, 3.33, -11.56],
 [1.56, 2.04, 3.39, -11.55],
 [1.56, 2.04, 3.26, -11.5],
 [0.69, 6.34, 3.45, -11.53],
 [0.69, 6.34, 3.2, -11.6],
 [0.69, 6.34, 3.33, -11.56],
 [0.69, 6.34, 3.39, -11.55],
 [0.69, 6.34, 3.26, -11.5],
 [1.14, 7.59, 3.45, -11.53],
 [1.14, 7.59, 3.2, -11.6],
 [1.14, 7.59, 3.33, -11.56],
 [1.14, 7.59, 3.39, -11.55],
 [1.14, 7.59, 3.26, -11.5],
 [1.35, 3.01, 3.45, -11.53],
 [1.35, 3.01, 3.2, -11.6],
 [1.35, 3.01, 3.33, -11.56],
 [1.35, 3.01, 3.39, -11.55],
 [1.35, 3.01, 3.26, -11.5],
 [0.92, 8.33, 3.45, -11.53],
 [0.92, 8.33, 3.2, -11.6],
 [0.92, 8.33, 3.33, -11.56],
 [0.92, 8.33, 3.39, -11.55],
 [0.92, 8.33, 3.26, -11.5]]
```

How can the desired output be achieved?
Kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not make sure each item is from the same index, and therein lies the problem! Here's a better possible solution:

```
for i, item in enumerate(l1): # i stores index
    r = item + l2[i] # Makes sure each item is from the same index
    l3.append(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use zip:

```
l3 = list()
for one, two in zip(l1, l2):
    l3.append(one + two)
```

Or the concise version using list comprehension:

```
l3 = [one + two for one, two in zip(l1, l2)]
```